# How much reduction of blood flow in the soft tissues can result from stress?

Tags: muscle, tendons, stress

I read on http://www.spine-health.com/glossary/muscle-tension:

> Stress may change the body's nervous system by constricting blood
>   vessels and reducing blood flow to the soft tissues, including
>   muscles, tendons, and nerves in the back.

Has any scientific study confirm and quantify that the reduction of blood flow in the soft tissues resulting from stress?

I am mostly interested in tendons that attach to the epicondyles at the elbow end of the humerus, and to a lesser extent in forearm muscles.